# What does requests.get("url address").raise_for_status() perform in requests package?

Tags: python-requests, http-status-codes, try-except

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
url = 'https://httpbin.org/'

try:
    response = requests.get(url) #get method of http will retreive all the data from specific url 
    # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
    print(response.status_code) #to know the http status code of requested url
    response.raise_for_status() #what does this line do 
except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}') 
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  #to handle any kind of
```

error Exception class is the main class for all kinds of exceptions

```
else:
    print('Success!')
```

Answer (score 1):

raise_for_status() returns an HTTPError object if an error has occurred during the process. It is used for debugging the requests module and is an integral part of Python requests. Python requests are generally used to fetch the content from a particular resource URI

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-raise_for_status-python-requests/#:~:text=raise_for_status()%20returns%20an%20HTTPError,from%20a%20particular%20resource%20URI](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-raise_for_status-python-requests/#:%7E:text=raise_for_status()%20returns%20an%20HTTPError,from%20a%20particular%20resource%20URI).